# Is there such a thing as פת מדינה?

Tags: parashat-bereishit, bentching, grapes-wine, kiddush, bread

In Bereishit, Hashem said to Adam

> בזעת אפך תאכל לחם

This would seem to imply that bread is universal to all people.

We also know that bread has a particular definition: it has to be made from one of the five grains.  Bentching after eating bread (כדי שביעה) is a Torah obligation, so this is a Torah level definition (at least according to the accepted halacha, Rabbi Akiva in Berachot 6:8 says you can bentch on any full meal).

But there have been cultures that didn't have bread.  The Aboriginal Australians, before European contact, had something called [bush bread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_bread), but it was made from plants other than the 5 grains, at least according to their standard identifications.  Although there is a kind of [barley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hordeum_pusillum) native to North America, it seems that most Native Americans (again, pre-European contact) made their [bread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bannock_(food)#Indigenous_North_Americans) from other crops, like corn.

For havdala, and possibly for kiddush and other purposes, we can use חמר מדינה instead of wine.  The Rashbam (Pesachim 107a) says another drink can become חמר מדינה if there is no real wine in the city; the Rambam is more lenient and says that if the people primarily drink something else instead of wine it becomes חמר מדינה.

Is there a similar concept of פת מדינה, in a place where there is no bread made from the 5 grains?  Would you be able to bentch on this "bread", or make kiddush on it according to those who say that חמר מדינה works for kiddush?

Comment: Before years I asked myself this question, if Beemet in Chine before ... years the function which is fulfilled by wheat in occident was fulfilled by rice, may be that the bracha hamotsi was applied to rice. Rabbi Akiva said אפילו אכל שלק הוא מזונו מברך עליו שלש ברכות. But I have no answer because maybe good for Birkat hamazon which is more linked to the funcion, and mayb not for motsi which is special for masbia. And maybe that the masbiut of rice is not particular. May be also for patatoes or corn in Americal continent  before 700 years

Comment: See Teshuvot R Avraham ben haRambam #85

Comment: @kouty I wasn't sure about rice, China is a huge place but my understanding is they have wheat too.  Rice might qualify for the Rambam's definition of chamar medina but not the Rashbam's.

Comment: @DoubleAA interesting, but I'm not sure that's relevant here, unless they didn't have any of the 5 grains in Yemen or only had a little.  Do we know what kinds of grain they were asking about?  They have the tradition of soft matza, which could indicate continuous availability of 5 grains, though it's not an absolute proof.

Comment: http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh3/1/453/1.htm

Comment: @hazoriz Yes, they don't become chametz, so we can't use them for matza.  It's not obvious that that means we can't bentch on them.

Comment: @Heshy Sorry typo I meant #84, where they ask about the blessing on 'Durah' ie. [sorghum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorghum). (Though reading it in context of #85 is interesting in it's own right.)

Comment: @DoubleAA that makes more sense, really interesting!!  His two answers to the claim about the mon are specific to Jews, either where most Jews live at any given time or Eretz Yisrael where we're supposed to live.  I wonder if he would agree that for non-Jews other types of grain can be considered bread, which would explain how Native Americans and Aboriginal Australians fulfilled בזעת אפך תאכל לחם.

Comment: It's not clear to me that Chamar Medina is a Deorayta concept. If it isn't you'd be hard pressed to expect a parallel for Benching.

Comment: Permitting chamar medina in place of wine is not synonymous with using the BRACHA of wine - you would say shehakol before and borei nefashos, not "al hagefen." Bentching is a bracha made on the consumption of bread, so while you might be able to substitute it for something like fulfilling your obligation of seudah by kiddush you almost certainly wouldn't be making a full bentching on it!

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky It's not obvious that bentching is only for bread, even though we pasken that it is.  http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berakhot.6.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: So we pasken that way... And? That means that it's only for bread. So you're admitting that I'm right, but that a person with a superficial understanding of sources might argue (against halacha) otherwise.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky You're right, I didn't articulate properly.  What I meant is: it's nonsense to say בורא פרי הגפן  on something that doesn't grow on a גפן, even if it is equivalent to wine.  Our text of bentching does not refer specifically to wheat barley rye oats spelt, which means that it's not nonsense to say on other things, it's just wrong, and there might be wiggle room in weird cases.  I was bringing those tanaim as evidence that it's not nonsense.  Actually, better evidence would be Orach Chayim 208:17.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yshar Koach for this shut RA Ben haRambam. There is somewhat I didn't understand in this teshuva. For Kiddush, the actual case of Yemen at this time was they have no Chamar Medina at all?, e.g. wine from temarim?

Comment: @kouty apparently. Muslims don't drink alcohol is the reason I guess

Answer (score 1):

Since all people can from Adam and Adam ate bread, it is the bread of all people, **if a group of people decided (to move to a different land and) not to eat bread, it does not change the definition of bread** even if they decide to call it that (unless the Torah also calls it that)

Even goyim came that people did not always live in Australia and America they came there from places where bread grows

---

My understanding is that the drink of the media can be used, becouse that what is says in the law, but we do not say hagofen on it, and not the meain shalosh

The idea is that the rabbinic law to make havdolo on an important drink did not mean sposificly wine but the most important drink that is available (which has some importance) so wine was always preferable

The law is learnt from the Torah to make an after brocho on bread made from wheat or barely which the rabbis explain include the 5 types of grains, (which seem to be the only grains with glutain)

---

The idea of the drink of the country is regarding the drinks **importance**

**But by bread (its importance is secondary) the legal thing needed is that it should be included in** **wheat and barley** so the costom of the country should not change the law

Comment: As I said before, you're probably right.  I'm looking for a source.

Comment: Also, you're really saying that the curse of בזעת אפך תאכל לחם was just for Adam himself and not לדורות?  That's hard to justify, especially since childbirth is still difficult and snakes still slither.

Comment: @Heshy no I did not say that, I say that people are not obligated to eat bread, Hashem gave them the right to stop, that posuk is regarding people that eat bread, and bread is something all people know about since there for fathers ate it

Comment: @Heshy no I did not say that, I say that people are not obligated to eat bread, Hashem gave them the right to stop, that posuk is regarding people that eat bread, and bread is something all people know about since there for fathers ate it

Comment: @Heshy for example Atkins stoped eating bread and rice and corn and potatoes (is his existence against the posuk?),  if he and his students  call ground beef or beans, bread it is also bread?

Comment: they are a small group of people; they wouldn't be able to define a חמר מדינה on their own either

Comment: @Heshy what will happen if these people become a big nation, as the Australians

Comment: Maybe the same thing that happens when the people who use apple juice instead of wine become a big nation?   This is basically the definition of chamar medina

Comment: @Heshy it does not become wine, it stays hamar hamedina, and the din is you can use it, but you say it becomes bread, a drink is a drink (maybe unless it is water), but you can't just come and say ANYTHING can be called bread,

Comment: Maybe it is pas hamedina and the din is you can use it.  I don't know, that's why I'm asking for proof that it is or isn't.  You haven't provided any evidence.

Comment: @Heshy you did not bring a prove why it can be, how can I prove it does not exist?

Comment: why should bread be different than wine?  Is it that obvious to you that it is?

Comment: a lot of people call corn bread 'bread'!

Answer (score 0):

Lechem in this context probably doesn't literally refer to bread alone.

You find other places in the Torah where Lechem was not a reference to bread but rather to life-sustaining food.

For example, The Monn which certainly wasn't bread was also referred to as Lechem

וַיִּרְא֣וּ בְנֵֽי־יִשְׂרָאֵ֗ל וַיֹּ֨אמְר֜וּ אִ֤ישׁ אֶל־אָחִיו֙
מָ֣ן ה֔וּא כִּ֛י לֹ֥א יָֽדְע֖וּ מַה־ה֑וּא וַיֹּ֤אמֶר משֶׁה֙
אֲלֵהֶ֔ם ה֣וּא הַלֶּ֔חֶם אֲשֶׁ֨ר נָתַ֧ן

Shemos 16:15

Comment: Why was the manna certainly not bread? They took it, ground it up, and cooked it. It wasn't wheat bread, but it was seemingly a baked-dough kind of food

Comment: The posuk refers to it in its present unrecognizable raw form as Lechem.

Comment: Sorry, but there's no "certainly" here, even if you can darshin the pesukim to fit your perspective

Comment: Lechem often means food in Tanach. For example, nosen lvhaima lachma. But that’s not of halachik importance.